# Querying WHERE column is IN ($array) returns only one row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to query all results where surveyid contains my array $subscibearray. The problem is the SQL query is only returning the first result (44 in this case) instead of all of them. I tried using mysql_fetch_array as well without any success. My results are being outputted via Table. Any help would be appreciated. I omitted as much code as possible to make this easy to read.

Array format:

```
$subscribearray = "" . join(', ',$subscribearray) . "";
```

`var_dump` of `$subscribearray`:

```
string(17) "'44, 35, 194, 36'"
```

query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                       FROM surveys 
                       WHERE surveyid IN ($subscribearray) 
                       ORDER BY peercompletetime DESC 
                       LIMIT 100") 
or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Please add code how you output your records.

Comment: And also explain - why you put ids in `'`?

Comment: Should I remove them? Sorry.

Comment: Yes, that should help.

Comment: you should also switch over to MySQLi, MySQLi is MySQL Improved. The reason behind this is because MySQL has been deprecated since around PHP 5. MySQLI is more secure and such. It isn't that hard, for example mysql_query becomes mysqli_query (note the i after mysql).

Comment: Tyler I will take this into consideration. Thank you.

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_` database extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php),
**a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world** it is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7)
Specially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) its really pretty easy

Comment: I love kittens this is terrible. Thanks for the link.

Comment: what do you get when you var_dump the $result? I'm mostly interesting in the num_rows and field_count values

Comment: If you think about how you would code an `IN()` query it would look like this `WHERE surveyid IN (1,2,3,4,5)` **and not** `WHERE surveyid IN ('1,2,3,4,5')` so that is what you have to mimic in your php statement that preps the data for this variable

Comment: Let me var_dump the num_rows and find out thanks

Comment: Of course every retest kills another kitten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should:

```
$subscribearray = join(',', $subscribearray); // 1,2,3
```

Or:

```
$subscribearray = "'" . join("','", $subscribearray) . "'"; // '1','2','3'
```

If you wrap all ids with a string, it will look for the string, and not separated values. ('1,2,3')

Of course, if it's a numeric column you should use the first one.